# Button does not appear clicked

Tags: android

I'm implementing a share option for my app. I built everything, and functionality-wise have no problems. My only problem is when I press the "share" buttons. Normally buttons change background color to slightly darker when you click them. However, my share buttons are not doing this and I have no idea why. Here is one of them:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/text_share"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
         android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:layout_width="65dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:src="@drawable/icon_sms"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:background="@color/primaryDark" />

     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
         android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:text="SMS"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my JAVA reads:

```
View textShare = findViewById(R.id.text_share);
textShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //share code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple and easy!

Make the `LinearLayout` clickable by adding `android:clickable="true"` to your LinearLayout's attributes.

#### Alternative answer

You don't need to use `LinearLayout`, you should create a regular `Button` and use `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableStart` to add images before text in a button, if you are trying to make a custom button, you can change the background, the text color, text size and other attributes. The file `styles.xml` will help you if you want to make your custom style global.